# Doctrine load fixtures --no-interaction flag is not working when running in a Symfony command

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

The --no-interaction flag on the doctrine:fixtures:load command is not working running within a Symfony command. It is working however via the terminal. I'm I calling it correctly?

When I run this from a bundle:

```
/**
 * Loads the fixtures
 * @param \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $oOutput
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface
 */
protected function loadFixturesCommand($oOutput) {
    $oOutput->writeln('<fg=white>Attempting to load fixtures</fg=white>');
    $updateCommand = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:fixtures:load');

    $updateArguments = array(
        'command' => 'doctrine:fixtures:load',
        '--no-interaction' => true,
    );

    $updateInput = new ArrayInput($updateArguments);
    $updateCommand->run($updateInput, $oOutput);

    try {
        $updateCommand->run($updateInput, $oOutput);
    } catch (ContextErrorException $e) {
        //..
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I get prompted to load the fixtures

But running this:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction
```

Doesn't prompt me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19):

I've found the solution.
Simply call:

```
$input->setInteractive(false);
```

Like so:

```
protected function loadFixturesCommand($oOutput) {
    $oOutput->writeln('<fg=white>Attempting to load fixtures</fg=white>');
    $updateCommand = $this->getApplication()->find('doctrine:fixtures:load');

    $updateArguments = array(
        'command' => 'doctrine:fixtures:load'
    );

    $updateInput = new ArrayInput($updateArguments);
    $updateInput->setInteractive(false);
    $updateCommand->run($updateInput, $oOutput);

    try {
        $updateCommand->run($updateInput, $oOutput);
    } catch (ContextErrorException $e) {
        //..
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a drop from your database you could also use this command I think, to be confirmed.

> By default Doctrine Data Fixtures uses DELETE statements to drop the existing rows from the database.
> If you want to use a TRUNCATE statement instead you can use the --purge-with-truncate flag:

```
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Symfony 6

```bash
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load -q
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `--append` param to suppress interaction.

i.e. `doctrine:fixtures:load --append`

Comment: The append option won't drop your current database before loading datafixtures, that's why it won't prompt you. Attended result cannot be the same ,after 2 calls